# Putting hyperlinks on Google sites using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sites, sites

I am trying to put a text (containing a hyperlink) using the click function in jQuery.

```
var publicationsText = "Rohit. <a href=\"http://www.google.com\" onmouseover=\"this.style.color=#EC4D48;\" onmouseout=\"this.style.color=#666;\" style=\"color:#666;\">Emerging Energy</a>";

    $('#publicationsID').click(function(){ 
      $("#homepage").html(publicationsText);
      return false;
    });
```

This works fine as intended on my local box. But when I publish this on Google sites, the HTML produced is:

```
<div id="container-caja-guest-0___">
<div id="homepage-caja-guest-0___">
Rohit.<a target="_blank" style="color: #666">Emerging Energy</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And the hyperlink is automatically removed.

Can any one please suggest a workaround that works on the Google sites?

Moreover the site is available at: http://www.wattalyst.org (and you can see the problem in Contact/Publications page)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason to use JavaScript (`onmouseover=\"this.style.color=#EC4D48;\" onmouseout=\"this.style.color=#666;\"`) fro simple CSS tasks? (`a { color: #666; } a:hover { color: #EC4D48; }`)

Comment: Yes the reason is that such CSS tasks (like hover) are not correctly  handled by Google sites, hence using the js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string is incorrectly formatted. You need to escape the quotes and merge the lines

```
var publicationsText = "Rohit. <a href=\"http://www.google.com\" "+
    " onmouseover=\"this.style.color=#EC4D48;\" onmouseout=\"this.style.color=#666;\" "+ 
    " style=\"color:#666;\">Emerging Energy</a>";
```

Comment: Ohh sorry posted the question wrongly, corrected it now. That's not the problem. Still with those changes it is not working on Google sites.

Comment: Why are you attempting this at all? I don't know anything about Google sites, but I had a quick look and it seems they have a wide variety of widgets that might suit your needs without having to program anything yourself. Not having to program seems kindof the point with Google sites, that's probably why they cripple Javascript.

Comment: Google sites doesn't provide the flexibility that I require in terms of design and layout. Hence I added an HTML box and adding all the code there.

Comment: Well it seems like they removed the ability to do what you want on purpose. My guess is that trying to circumvent their restrictions might lead to the disabling of your website.

Comment: Might be possible, but I am sure there must be a workaround, just as `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` are workaround for `hover`.

Comment: Looking at the HTML generated, that just looks plain horrible. All the text on the page is javascript. That will probably not be google-searchable at all. Why do you do it this way? There's nothing especially tricky about your content, just bullet points with text and a link, you should be able to accomplish that with the built in designer.

Comment: Yup now doing it as per the robust and more searchable way. Multiple pages.

Answer (score 1):

You're building your `HTML` string incorrectly (not escaping double quotes):

```
var publicationsText = "Rohit. <a href=\"http://www.google.com\"" +
    "onmouseover=\"this.style.color=#EC4D48;\"" +
    "onmouseout=\"this.style.color=#666;\"" +
    "style=\"color:#666;\">Emerging Energy</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have escaping of double quotes in href